# custom cursor adapter wrong position

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

i have a custom cursor adapter that fetches date from database and populate list , and its **onlistItemClick** listener i show a view attached to that row, and then hide that view by clicking it again,
everything is working fine, but i have two problems,
1)- i have 10 rows, it shows 10, but when i log positions, it gives me only those positions, that fits to screen.
2)- when i click on a row, view appears that is attached to that row, but when i scroll down, i found another view is visible down the screen,

here is my adapter,

```
    public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater; 

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
        textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text")));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        //in that "list_layout.xml" i made a view that has to show and hide on click listener
        View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        if(cursor.getPosition()%2 != 0)
        {
            rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I am working from hours to figure out the issue, but in vain..
Please help any care taker.

Comment: sorry i couldnnt understand your 2nd issue.. can you elaborate it?

Comment: it works fine for the rows that fits on screen as i already said, but when i scroll down, log doew not give new positions
like,if 5 records appear on screen, it will give 0-4
when i scroll down, it start from 0 again..

Comment: what you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: Where are you logging these row numbers ?

Comment: in new view method, 
int position = cursor.getPosition();
   Log.d("Position", "" + position);

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1 : Android initializes rows that fit in the screen at a given time not all of them at once for performance issues.

Answer to question 2 : try providing an else clause like this :

```
if(cursor.getPosition()%2 != 0)
{
   rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
}
else
{
   rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.deawable.whatever); // your view for even number rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing getView method instead.

For example:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        if (getCursor().getPosition() % 2 != 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
        }else{

            convertView.setBackgroundResource(<-Something->);
        }
        return convertView;

    }
```

EDIT

```
 @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
        textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text")));
        if(cursor.getPosition()%2 != 0)
        {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i removed newview() method, and used yours, it gave me error to add unimplemented method newview(), i added that default method, and then getview() doesnt call

Comment: Then try moving this code: 
 if(cursor.getPosition()%2 != 0)
        {
            rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
        }
To bindView as well