# Custom cursoradapter wrong position

Tags: android

when I click  call_btn button, it shows wrong position !

like this picture is my listview :

(The red numbers are wrong)

[image]

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter
    {
        Context b;

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            b= (Context) context;
      }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_numer);

        tv1.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        tv2.setText(cursor.getString(3));


        final Button call_btn= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);    

        call_btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) { 

               Toast.makeText(b, cursor.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }}); 


     }

        protected Context getActivity() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
     }
}
```

I've seen these quastions before:

[Wrong position in Custom Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887903/wrong-position-in-custom-adapter)

[custom cursor adapter wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278974/custom-cursor-adapter-wrong-position)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `Cursor` is just a result set from the database with a position pointer into the current row. As you scroll your list and new rows are filled in based on your cursor data, this position pointer is *automatically moved for you* under the covers.

So when `bindView()` is called for each row in your list, the position is set correctly, which is why your TextViews have the correct text, but when the `call_btn.onClick()` is called, we don't know what the cursor's current position is, and there is definitely no guarantee that it's pointing to the same position that it was when `onClickListener` was instantiated when `bindView()` was called.

The solution is pretty simple. Try replacing your `bindView()` method with this edited version below, which explicitly saves the position and then uses that to move the cursor to the right row in the `onClick()` method:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_numer);

    tv1.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    tv2.setText(cursor.getString(3));


    final Button call_btn= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);    
    final int position = cursor.getPosition();

    call_btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) { 

           cursor.moveToPosition(position);
           Toast.makeText(b, cursor.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }}); 


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is to save position to buttons tag by setTag(cursor.getPosition()); to your call_btn:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_numer);

    tv1.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    tv2.setText(cursor.getString(3));

    final Button call_btn= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);    
    call_btn.setTag(cursor.getPosition());

    call_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity) context).onBtnClick((int)v.getTag());
        }
    });
}
```

onClickListener then passes position to your activity, where you just declare:

```
public void onBtnClick(int position) {
    // do your stuff
}
```